# Is Hodge decomposition detected in Clifford multiplication

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spin-geometry

This is a bit of a vague question, sorry for that. I am wondering if there's any detection of Hodge decomposition in terms of Clifford multiplication. For example if $\phi$ is a spinor and $\theta,\alpha$ are closed and coclosed forms respectively, can we say anything about $\theta\cdot\phi$ and $\alpha\cdot\phi$, how to differentiate between this two end products if possible? Any other input or reference is welcome as well.

It might not be a question suitable for this site. Let me know in that case, I will delete it.